# log-file needs to get cleaned manually after any fault in tex-file

Tags: miktex, texstudio

Once I did a fault within a syntax or something similar, I get a fault that is shown in the console and within the log-file.
After fixing the fault and recompiling the document, I get the same error again, which is obviously not present anymore.
The only help to fix this misbehavior is to clean the log-file manually by removing the entire content.

This workaround is super bothering ...
I'm using TexStudio and MikTex.

Did one have this problem before and knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: The log file is overwritten every time you compile the `tex` file. Maybe this is some kind of bug of TeXStudio? (but I don't think so)

Comment: The `.log` file just contains a log of errors, warnings and other compilation info of your LaTeX run. It is automatically written every time you run TeX and it is not read by TeX. In particular it does not (usually, you could in theory construct counterexamples ...) have an influence on whether or not your next LaTeX run throw an error. There should be no need to delete the `.log` file....

Comment: ...  **But** the behaviour you describe can occur with other auxiliary files, most notably `.aux`, `.toc`, `.lof`, `.bbl`. Errors in your document may prevail in those files for an additional run even if they are fixed in the `.tex` source. That is due to the two-pass nature of the code using them: If there is an error in your document that manifests itself in the `.aux` file (for example, it's the same for `.toc` and `.lof`), the error will usually only occur on the second TeX run. ...

Comment: ... If you fix the `.tex` source, the problematic code may remain in the auxiliary files until the next successful TeX run. But if the error blocks a successful run, you can only resolve the issue by trying to force the TeX run past the error or by removing the temporary file. I'm afraid there is no better workaround for issues like these (except of course for avoiding errors in the first place).

Comment: What you wrote is what i'd expect, too.  But the reality Shows that cleaning the content of the log file solves the problem until the next syntax error. I dont know why it's like that but i'd like to fix it

Comment: I really cannot for the life of me imagine a situation where the `.log` file could be the one file causing this problem unless the document contained some very artificial code that explicitly tried to involve the `.log` file. Is there any chance you could give us a step-by-step guide to reproduce the issue you are getting with the `.log` file (a short example document)?

Comment: Perhaps we're misunderstanding what you are trying to say.  If an error is in the main `.tex` file, and doesn't cause a related error to be written out to an `.aux` file (for instance), then, yes, correcting that error in the source will not result in an error with the next run.  But it is never necessary to remove the `.log` file when recompiling because the `.log` file will always be overwritten.

Comment: Well, I really do nothing else than erase the entire content of my main .tex file. I don not delete it, i just remove all of its content. Do you think it will work if i remove the aux-files after compilation?

Comment: Hang on! Do you erase the contents of your `.log` file (that's how I read your question) or do you remove the contents of your `.tex` file (that's how I read your comment)? I don't know if removing the `.aux` file helps in your case, but as I described above there is a certain class of problems where removing the `.aux` file *after also fixing the underlying error in the `.tex` code* is the best (and almost only) way to get things going again.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. i only erase the content of the log file. I'll check if it can be fixed when I delete the aux files after compilation

Comment: I just tested your proposal. Removing all aux-files did not help. There seems to be an dependency between Tex and this log-file... 
I just entered "\beg" to provoke a fault, compile it, remove all aux files and compile it again. It didn't work... Afterwards, I removed the line " [6]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.100" from the log-file and voila, it works again... Same effect if i clean the entire content of this log-file..

Comment: Can you add a full step-by-step guide to reproduce the issue to your question please (you can and in fact are encouraged to edit your question to include essential information)? If it helps you can in addition add a copy-and-paste of any error messages you get and screenshots of what you are doing. At the moment it's not quite clear to me what exactly "it didn't work" means (at what level did it not work? how could you tell? because your editor says something?). I'm beginning to suspect this might just be an issue with how you editor interprets and remembers error messages from the `.log` ...

Comment: ... and may have nothing to do with TeX itself. It would certainly help if you could try and test if the same pattern of errors and `.log` files persists if you try to compile your document from the command line instead of going through an editor.

Comment: I just figured out what the problem was.. Please have a look my answer below.. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution for my issue.
Texstudio was configured to execute Bibtex and PDFLatex in this order after pressing the compilation button.
**I added another execution of PDFLatex before Bibtex and now the issue seems to be fixed.**
If I had a fault, I fixed it and recompiled my document, I don't need to cleanup the log-file again.

Maybe Bibtex is checking the log-file before executing the program itself?